# AndEngine ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, andengine

Today I started working on AndEngine and am facing problems very early. Tried some example code to just set the background to some colour and it throws ClassNotFoundException. Tried cleaning the project, changing the workspace. Need Some Help...

This is my class

```
    package com.Try4;

    import org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine;
    import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
    import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
    import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions.ScreenOrientation;
    import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
   import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
     import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.background.ColorBackground;
   import org.anddev.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
     import org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;

   import android.view.Display;


   public class Try4Activity extends BaseGameActivity{


private Camera mCamera;

private Scene mMainScene;

@Override
public Engine onLoadEngine() {

    final Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        int cameraWidth = display.getWidth();

        int cameraHeight = display.getHeight();



        mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, cameraWidth, cameraHeight);



        return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE,

            new RatioResolutionPolicy(cameraWidth, cameraHeight), mCamera));

}

@Override
public void onLoadResources() {


}

@Override
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());



        mMainScene = new Scene();

        mMainScene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));

        return mMainScene;


}

@Override
public void onLoadComplete() {


}
```

}

And here is my manifest.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.Try4"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
     <application
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name" >
     <activity
        android:name=".Try4Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
```

Stack Trace

```
 05-20 07:28:56.015: W/dalvikvm(351): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception              (group=0x4001b188)
 05-20 07:28:56.045: E/AndroidRuntime(351): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to    uncaught exception
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.Try4/com.Try4.Try4Activity}:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Try4.Try4Activity in loader   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44c066a8
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  com.Try4.Try4Activity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44c066a8
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
05-20 07:28:56.065: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  ... 11 more
05-20 07:28:56.086: I/dalvikvm(351): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
05-20 07:28:56.106: I/dalvikvm(351): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: did you try to `Clean` the project?

Comment: @MoshErsan tried it. Even tried creating new project.

Comment: go to `Project Properties` then select `Java Build Path`, then select `Order And Export`, check `andengine` library and any other lib you use, i think this may helps you

Comment: @MoshErsan thanks a ton mate. Got it working. But can you explain what went wrong??

Comment: the compiler didnt include the `andengine` to your code, so when you try to launch the activity, `dalvik` was trying to initiate an instance of `BaseGameActivity` and its not found.

Comment: check this question [classNotFoundException][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677749/android-classnotfoundexception#comment13855935_10677749

Answer (score 1):

You should not use capitals in the package name... Should be `com.try4.Try4Activity`

Comment: you want me to refactor the package or just change its use in manifest.xml??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line of your Manifest file:

```
 <activity
    android:name=".Try4Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Instead use this:

```
<activity
    android:name="package.subpackage.projectname.Try4Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```